# How to say "for" in Chinese?

Tags: translation, traditional-characters

I'm trying to say "the park is great for playing" but I can only think about saying 公園很好玩的地方。Is there a way where I can describe the park as being a good or the best place for playing? thanks

Answer (score 4):

> "The park is (**for**) playing" = 這公園(**是用於**)遊樂(**的**)
>
> *or 這公園是遊樂(**用的***)

~

> "The park is great (**for**) playing" = 這公園是很適合(**用於**)遊樂(**的**)
>
> *or 這公園是很適合(**於**)遊樂(**用的**)*

Other example:

"Handgun is (**for**) killing people" = "手槍是(**用於**)殺人(**的**)" or "手槍是殺人(**用的**)"

"Handgun is good (**for**) killing people" = "手槍是很適合(**用於**)殺人(**的**)" or "手槍是很適合(**於**)殺人(**用的**)"

> 用於 is a more literary term. The colloquial term is 用来

Answer (score 3):

I think you won't always use a Chinese word for **for** when translating. Your sentence doesn't need it.

The park is a great place for playing in.
这个公园是一个玩耍的好地方。

Mostly, **for** will turn up in translation, when you need it, as 给 or 为

I want all of you students to write poems **for me**.
我想让你们所有人**给我**写诗。

Please write something for me.
请**为我**写点什么。